# How to re-request FB permissions in Hello.js?

Tags: hello.js

I am using Hello.js to connect with FB (asking for the default permissions). However a user has an option to edit his provided info and uncheck an email address. I can capture this action, but not sure how to re-request the permissions again, so he would have to grant his email in order to proceed.

My coffescript snippet:

```
hello('facebook').login().then ((json) =>

    hello('facebook').api( '/me' ).then((json) =>

      if json.email
          @proceed(json)
      else 
          @rerequestPermissions(json)

      return
    )
    return
  )
```

Comment: Currently this user-override is not tracked by HelloJS. Can you create a ticket?

Comment: Created. https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/issues/234